# Retrieve filetype:pdf from library

Tags: python, file-system

I retrieved all the books in `pdf` from my library with a recursive function.

```
import os

def walk(dirname):
    for name in os.listdir(dirname):
        path = os.path.join(dirname, name)

        if os.path.isfile(path) and path.endswith('pdf'):
            books.append(path)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            walk(path)
def main():
    dir = '~/Documents/MyLibrary/'
    global books
    books = []
    walk(dir)
    print(books)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similarly to a feature in most UNIX shells, Python has a globbing module, called [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

It even supports the extended globbing (using `**` to recursively descend into sub-folders) since Python 3.5, which you can use like this:

```
import os
from glob import glob

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/MyLibrary/')
    books = glob(os.path.join(dir, "**/*.pdf"), recursive=True)
    print(books)
```

Here I also used the `os.path` module to correctly join the paths and expand the `~` symbol to the users home directory.

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) object (introduced in Python 3.4), which also supports globbing:

```
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir = Path('~/Documents/MyLibrary/').expanduser()
    books = list(dir.glob('**/*.pdf'))
    print(books)
```

Note the `list` call, which is necessary, because the `Path.glob` method returns a generator (in contrast to `glob.glob`, which returns a list).

Comment: This is a solution I dare not to imagine, surprise :>

Answer (score 6):

You are essentially imitating the behaviour of [`os.walk`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/os#os.walk) function, which is already present in python.

[Here is a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5141829/1190388) minor implementation of [`fnmatch`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/fnmatch) to filter out a glob-based file-pattern from the `os.walk`'s result. Since, you do not need an exclude section, your implementation would be easier. Although, personally; I'd go with `.endswith` check as it is easier to read (and more pythonic).

---

More importantly, using global variable is a very bad design practice and must be avoided. You can define a new function `get_files_of_type`, which takes a parameter of type of files to filter out, and another parameter for the source path, and simply returns the list generated after `os.walk`. A rough implementation would look like (untested):

```
def get_files_of_types(path='.', file_types=None):
    """
    path: string depicting the path which is to be walked
    file_types: list of extensions to be checked against
    """
    if file_types is None:
        file_types = ['pdf']
    book_list = []
    for root, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        books = [
            os.path.join(root, f)
            for f in files if f.endswith(tuple(file_types))
        ]
        book_list.append(books)
    return book_list
```

Comment: How about using [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) instead of `str.endswith`?

Comment: @Coal_ with `.endswith`, a user may chose to provide either `.pdf` or `pdf`.

Comment: A docstring would be really helpful for this method, because `get_files_of_type(".", ".pdf")` would produce interesting results (since `tuple` will be called on `file_types`, it produces `('.', 'p', 'd', 'f')`).

Comment: Also, I would call it `get_files_of_types` to make it clearer that an iterable of types must be supplied.